# How to split string using pattern matching?

Tags: c, arrays, split, strtok, strstr

I have a string like "123-#-#-abc-user-#-#-abcpassword-#-#-123456", i need to split this string with pattern "-#-#-" to create an array. I used the following code to do this

```
    char buf[5000];
    strcpy(buf, "123-#-#-abc-user-#-#-abcpassword-#-#-123456");
    int i = 0;
    char *p = strtok (buf, "-#-#-");
    char *array[5000];

    int items = 0;
    while (p != NULL)
    {
        items++;
        array[i++] = p;
        p = strtok (NULL, "-#-#-");
    }
```

But the result isn't getting for "123-#-#-abc-user-#-#-abcpassword-#-#-123456" due to the hyphen in the "abc-user". What i am expecting is that array[0] has the 123, array[1] has abc-user, array[2] as abcpassword etc. Is there any other method to split to array with the exact pattern ?

Comment: read the manuel of `strtok()`, it's only match character not string !

Comment: In [`strtok()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strtok.html) the second argument `"-#-#-"` means: 'tokenize on "-" **or** "#" **or** "-" **or** "#" **or** "-"'. Use another function, eg [`strstr()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strstr.html).

Answer (score 4):

`strtok()` here will not produce the exact output you expect. Check the details, `C11`, chapter §7.24.5.8

> A sequence of calls to the strtok function breaks the string pointed to by `s1` into a
>   sequence of tokens, each of which is delimited by **a character from the string pointed to
>   by `s2`.** [...]

So, presence of *any* character of the whole delimiter string will cause tokenization.

You need to look for [`strstr()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/strstr) which searches for a sub string inside a bigger string. Once again, from `C11`, chapter 7.24.5.7

> ```
> char *strstr(const char *s1, const char *s2);
> ```
>
> The `strstr` function locates the first occurrence in the string pointed to by `s1` of the
>   sequence of characters (excluding the terminating null character) in the string pointed to
>   by `s2`.

and

> The `strstr` function returns a pointer to the located string, or a null pointer if the string
>   is not found. [...]

So you can

- use the function call,
- take the non-null returned pointer
- perform pointer arithmetic to reach to the next token you want.